# How to return true labels of items when using predict_generator?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am observing the output of my neural network with `predict_generator()` function but I am unable to see true labels of the predicted items. How can I implement a block to see the true labels of the input items?

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255,
rotation_range=45,
width_shift_range=0.25,
height_shift_range=0.25,
horizontal_flip=True,
)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    evaluate_path,
    target_size=(width, height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),      loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
x = model.predict_generator(test_generator, val_samples=1)
print(x)
```

Comment: predict_generator() returns a numpy array with all the predictions. Can you provide your code and give more details where you have a problem?

Comment: I want to see the prediction and the true label together

Comment: They want to know how to "yield the results of a generator", basically.

Comment: You missed a definition of `test_generator`.

Answer (score 3):

Try following function:

```
from six import next

def generator_with_true_classes(model, generator):
    while True:
        x, y = next(generator)
        yield x, model.predict(x), y
```

It will yield original data, `y_pred` and `y_true`. Use it in a following way:

```
nb_of_samples = 0
nb_of_samples_to_compute = 100 # set your own value
for x, y_pred, y_true in generator_with_true_classes(model, test_generator):
    # do something with data, eg. print it.
    nb_of_samples += 1
    if nb_of_samples == nb_of_samples_to_compute:
         break
```

Comment: <generator object generator_with_true_classes at 0x7fc9b80aba40> is the output

Comment: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 250, 250, 3)'

Comment: Are you sure your generator is working properly? How many images has it found?

Comment: Found 326 images belonging to 2 classes.

Comment: Weird - but try now.